# No method error when deploying to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rails with sqlite in developement and mysql in production. I get previous daya using this method `Date.today.prev_day(n=3)`. This works fine in development but when deploying to production get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `prev_day' for Sun, 09 Jun 2013:Date)
```

Comment: Can you show the full backtrace?

Comment: Started POST "/home/gettotalselled" for 41.238.53.10 at Sun Jun 09 11:21:08 +0200 2013
Processing by HomeController#gettotalselled as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `prev_day' for Sun, 09 Jun 2013:Date):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:21:in `gettotalselled'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:18:in `each'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:18:in `gettotalselled'

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using on the deployment server vs. development? Is this a brand new deployment or has it been working in the past?

Comment: i tried also in rails console in production and get the same error:Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.8)
irb(main):001:0> Date.today
=> Sun, 09 Jun 2013
irb(main):002:0> Date.today.prev_day
NoMethodError: undefined method `prev_day' for Sun, 09 Jun 2013:Date

Comment: rails version on production : (Rails 3.2.8) in same produciton and development and this brand new development

Comment: The Ruby version, not Rails. Run `ruby -v`

Comment: Ruby version in development : ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux] and in production ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I was thinking it might be an old version of Ruby on the deployment server but that's looking less likely now. Just to be certain, in the `irb` session where you can reproduce this issue, what does the constant `RUBY_VERSION` return? I.e., type `RUBY_VERSION` into irb

Comment: Ruby ersion from irb "1.9.3"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `yesterday` method:

```
1.9.3p392 :011 > Date.today
 => Sun, 09 Jun 2013 
1.9.3p392 :012 > Date.yesterday
 => Sat, 08 Jun 2013 
1.9.3p392 :013 > Date.yesterday.yesterday
 => Fri, 07 Jun 2013
```

Or if you need to specify a specific number of days prior, stick with the prev_day method, but try removing n=3 and just use the integer like

```
Date.today.prev_day(3)
```

If this isn't working you probably have an older version of Ruby on your production server.

Just use the equivalent method **Date - n**

```
1.9.3p392 :017 > Date.today-3
 => Sun, 09 Jun 2013
```

Comment: All , Thanks for your help , i used Date.today-3 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a version of ruby prior to 1.9.1 on your production machine. According to [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/Date/prev_day) `prev_day`was introduced with version 1.9.1.